# Use a button to transfer values to a text file in php

Tags: php, html

I need your help. Atm Im programming a php script that writes a single text input to a text file from an HTML input box. Heres the code:

```
<center>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="APIkey" id="APIkey" value="API Key">
    </form>
</center>
```

The user of the website should enter the APIkey into the textbox and then he should press a button to transfer the APIkey to the following php script to write it in the APIkey.txt

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("APIkey.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = APIkey;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: You can use AJAX method for send API to the given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do some changes on your code, to make it work as per your requirements.Create a text file in the same directory of your php file. Simple way is below

```
<center>
  <form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="APIkey" id="APIkey" value="API Key">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
  </form>
</center>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $myfile = fopen("APIkey.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = $_REQUEST['APIkey'];
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```

Comment: If it help you can make the answer as helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's time for read good tutorial about PHP Request.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="APIkey" id="APIkey" value="API Key">
</form>
```

You have send your data with GET Method but for a long text it's not recommanded to pass by url

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="APIkey" id="APIkey" value="API Key">
</form>

    <?php

    // For information
    var_dump($_POST);

    if(isset($_POST["APIkey"]) {

    $myfile = fopen("APIkey.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $_POST["APIkey"];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

   }
?>
```

Comment: Yea, lets all send sensitive info like apikeys with GET requests ^^